# getresponse recaptcha in angular 4 form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new in angular and I want to know how to change property `disabled` in a button, with get-response recaptcha in angular 4 `form.component`

I try with this but not working:

```
  <div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
  <form class="login-form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario" required/>     
  <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required/>
 <div >
 <re-captcha class="g-recaptcha" (resolved)="resolved($event)" 
 siteKey="6LcOuyYTAAAAAHTjFuqhA52fmfJ_j5iFk5PsfXaU">
 </re-captcha>
  </div>
  <button id="entrarbtn" onclick="captcha;" (click)="submit()" type="submit" 
  disabled>Entrar</button>
  <p class="message">No se ha registrado? <a href="/registrar">Cree una 
  cuenta</a>
  </p>

    <script>
    var captcha = function ()
    {var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    if(response.length == 0)
    {return false;}    
    else
    {$("#entarbtn").prop("disable"), false;
    return true;
    }};
    </script>
  </form>
 </div>
 </div>
```

in `login.component.ts`

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import {Router} from "@angular/router";
   export interface FormModel {
   captcha?: string;} 
   @Component({
   selector: 'app-login',
   templateUrl: './login.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    public submit(): void {this.router.navigate(['/pagina']);}
    constructor(private router: Router)
    { }
    ngOnInit() {}
    }
```

Comment: You should really put this in a JSFiddle or something to organize it better so people actually want to help you.

Comment: I guess you can use `[disabled]="captcha()"`